# TapkuLibrary.h not found on archive

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, tapku

Everything's fine building in xcode and testing the app until I built in for archive.

I am capable of running my program in xcode and it does really work.

My problem is that when I tried to archive the project the error come out.

This is the error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Error issue
'TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h' file not found
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have different Header search paths for develop/archive/release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have different Header search paths for develop/archive/release?[image]

Comment: That just did for me! Thanks!