# TapkuLibrary.h and <TapkuLibrary> not found - Lexical and Preprocessor Issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, tapku

I've had huge troubles with this for quite a while now.
A few days ago after rebuilding my project, I got an error saying "TapkuLibrary.h" was not found. I removed the files attached to the project and followed the directions exactly directed at https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

However, when I tried to rebuild my project, the file is still not found!

I'm using XCode 4.6.1 building for iOS 6.1

I can see that the files attached to the xcode project from Tapku can be found because I can find them in the side bar. For some reason though, TapkuLibrary.h is not found.

Also, when I control a class, it links me to the right symbol for all files except TapkuLibrary.h which is, again, not found.

I'm quite stressed by this, so any clues would be immensely appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

UPDATE:
I've tried gain to remove all the files and readd them to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried to take the file from here https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/blob/master/src/TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h and add it manually to your project?

Comment: I have the physical TapkuLibrary.h file but it won't link for some reason! XCode 4.6.1 does not detect it and can't find the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the solution in this question: [TapkuLibrary.h not found on archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280784/tapkulibrary-h-not-found-on-archive?rq=1)

I think it's exactly the same issue you're having.